Use TraslateService in standalone components accross Angular microfrontends and Webpack Module Federation
Which is the best way to use the TraslateService (ngx-translate) accross microfrontends in an Angualar application with Webpack Module Federation using standalone components?
I was importing TranslateModule.forChild() in every module exposed by microfrontends, but I can't do it anymore exposing standalone components instead of old Angular modules.
